# Equivalent options for gfortran vs ifort

Tags: gnu, gfortran, intel-fortran

I used to compile a code with `ifort` and the following options:

```
-openmp -O2 -i-static -i8 -g -mkl -p -132
```

I want to compile with `gfortran` now, but the options are different. I know that `-openmp` equivalent is `-fopenmp`, but if someone could help me with the rest that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what are the flags expected to do. That way people who know the gfortran flags don't have to study the Intel Fortran manuals for you.

Answer (score 1):

-mkl option will be recognized by Intel Fortan compiler only.
In the case of gnu fortran, to link with Intel MKL, please check how to do that  with MKL linker Adviser follow the link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor
e.x – static linking:  -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl